# Laravel, Route not defined. yet it is

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

I'm developing an eccomerce site. and im getting this error on checkout. please help [image]

here are the defined routes:

```
//payfast payment

Route::get('payment', 'PaymentController@confirmpayment')->name('confirmPayment');
Route::get('/payfast/success','PaymentController@success')->name('payment.success');
Route::get('/payfast/cancel','PaymentController@cancel')->name('payment.cancel');
```

and here is the Controller (destination route):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use NunoMaduro\Collision\Provider;
use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Product;
use DB;
use Billow\Contracts\PaymentProcessor;






Class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    

    public function confirmpayment(PaymentProcessor $payfast)
    {
        $cart = Cart::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('order_id',null)->get()->toArray();
        
        $data = [];
```

Comment: The error shows you have some code somewhere which is trying to use a route named `payment`.  You showed us 3 routes with names, but none of the names are `payment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [Laravel Named Route `name()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes), you have to use it.

> `Route::get('payment', 'PaymentController@confirmpayment')->name('confirmPayment')`;

---

Instead  of using

```
payment
```

replace it with

```
confirmPayment
```

Answer (score 0):

change your HTTP method from get to post
like this:
`Route::post('payment', 'PaymentController@confirmpayment')->name('confirmPayment')`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't have route named `payment` you only have

```
confirmPayment
payment.success
payment.cancel
```